# Pandas series attributes disappearing/inaccessible - converting list of series to DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, series

### **Context:**

I have a small stack of data that I'm working with, hourly entries on a daily form, c. 110 entries or something. I'm trying to develop aggregate counts for each list item at each hour.

Each hourly entry has multiple values (from a fixed set) in `string` form. Which tabled looks approximately like this:

| Time | Date | Date | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1200 | ['jog', ' fly', 'swim'] | ['fly', 'swim', fly', 'swim'] | ['work', 'slave'] |
| 1300 | None | ['jog', ' fly', 'swim', 'jog', ' fly', 'swim'] | ['jog', ' fly', 'swim', 'code'] |

It started as `.csv`, I've then converted to `.json` for storage, and then to `DataFrame` for manipulation. I have used the following list comprehension with `value_counts()` to get the counts for each column/series:

`[counts.append(data[col].explode().value_counts(dropna=False)) for col in data if 'Fill in today' in col]`

Now I have a problem where I'm trying to convert the value counts into their own dataframe so I can actually make sense of the data. For some reason when I access `counts[0][0]` I get the first count (eg. `1` for jog from the table above) which makes perfect sense, but when I access `counts[0].name` I get `count` and when I access `counts[0].attrs` I get this:

```
Index(['Jog',None,'Work','Swim','Slave','Fly',dtype='object',name='1200')
```

The series returned by `count[0]` looks like this:

| count |  |
| --- | --- |
| 1200 |  |
| Jog | 1 |
| Fly | 3 |
| Swim | 3 |
| work | 1 |
| slave | 1 |

When I convert the list `counts` to a `DataFrame` I get an object with multiple series called `counts` and columns headed by the activity value and the attribute `name='1200'` has disappeared completely.

### **Questions:**

What is it that I'm missing, or that I don't understand, that is preventing me from converting a list of 25 of these `series` to a *useful* dataframe?

Where does the series name go? How can I access it? How can I utilize it to convert my data into a useful data frame where the activity/item and the hour are the indices and columns and the counts are the counts?

| item | 1200 | 1300 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jog | 1 | 2 |
| swim | 2 | 54 |

Answer (score 2):

The exact logic is unclear, but I envision you might need to flatten the "Date" columns to 1D using [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), then count your values and reshape:

```
out = (df.set_index('Time').stack().explode()
         .groupby(level=0).value_counts().unstack('Time', fill_value=0)
         .rename_axis(index='time', columns=None).reset_index()
       )
```

Or with [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
tmp = df.set_index('Time').stack().explode().reset_index()

out = (pd.crosstab(tmp[0], tmp['Time'])
         .rename_axis(index='time', columns=None).reset_index()
       )
```

Output:

```
    time  1200  1300
0    fly     1     1
1   code     0     1
2    fly     2     2
3    jog     1     3
4  slave     1     0
5   swim     3     3
6   work     1     0
```

Used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
{'index': [0, 1],
 'columns': ['Time', 'Date', 'Date', 'Date'],
 'data': [[1200,
   ['jog', ' fly', 'swim'],
   ['fly', 'swim', 'fly', 'swim'],
   ['work', 'slave']],
  [1300,
   None,
   ['jog', ' fly', 'swim', 'jog', 'fly', 'swim'],
   ['jog', 'fly', 'swim', 'code']]],
 'index_names': [None],
 'column_names': [None]},
orient='tight')
```